# binding rethinkdb webUI to 'localhost' and proxy: refuses connections or exposes to full network

Tags: proxy, rethinkdb

I am not able to successfully bind and [secure the rethinkdb http client](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/security/#binding-the-web-interface-port), either being exposed to the whole network or refusing connections behind the proxy.

I am thus left with no choice but to restart the rdb daemon with bind-http=all each
time I want to access it...

Rdb starts with systemctl under archlinux. Three configurations I tried:

```
# /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/mydb.conf

bind-http=localhost     #(1)
bind-http=127.0.0.1     #(2)
bind-http=1.2.3.4       #(3)
```

Resulting in:

1. Fails to parse 'localhost'
2. Refuses connections behind the proxy
3. Equivalent to `bind-http=all`

Firefox 59 uses a socks proxy, working ok
as the browser's ip address does become 1.2.3.4:

```
$ ssh -TND 8080 user@1.2.3.4
```

I am quite convinced that I had secured the http client as expected,
and problems started after I updated both FF and rdb 
(FF59 fails to parse 'localhost' as well for example)

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature or if I am missing something,
any help is most welcome. Many thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. You can only restrict access inside rethinkdb between the different network interfaces, where I asume you only have a public interface, and a loopback interface (localhost). 

If you have a proxy, and you want to limit traffic to only accept request from that proxy, you need to control that with firewall rules, either with an external firewall, or with iptables in linux.

Comment: Hmm thanks will look into that. I thought it was not necessary to use iptables as this is not mentioned in the docs... I expected FF using a socks proxy would cause the server to interpret my browser's http requests as originating from the loopback interface

Comment: If you bind rethinkdb to 127.0.0.1, then using an SSH tunnel should work, but I don't understand your syntax. Basically, it should be `ssh -N -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 user@1.2.3.4` and then http://localhost:8080 in FF should work. Not sure why you are talking about both SOCKS and SSH, those are completely different concepts.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with say `ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8084` and `http-port=8084` on the rdb server side but FF hangs on  `localhost:8080`...

Comment: I'm talking about both SOCKS and SSH because this is how it is walked through in this specific [paragraph](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/security/#binding-the-web-interface-port) of the docs, and used to work as expected. Honestly I'd be **more than happy** to drop the FF about:preferences > socks part, and to access this !$ interface without exposing it to the whole network.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your precious advice @jishi, I figured it out... Thanks to some new FF59 default setting you need to visit `127.0.0.1:8080` instead of  `localhost:8080`. The socks proxy is indeed useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of the "localhost" string.
Configuring the rethinkdb server with:

```
#/etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/mydb.conf
bind-http=127.0.0.1
http-port=8084
```

and binding some local port with SSH:

```
[client]$ ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8084 server
```

is enough to access the web interface at [127.0.0.1:8080](http://127.0.0.1:8080), as suggested by @jishi.

Configuring the browser to use a SOCKS proxy as per the rdb docs is not at all necessary.

For some reason [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080) is not understood by FF59  (gets invisibly prefixed by www or something).

Comment: I think for non-standard ports, you need to use full url `http://localhost:8080` in some browsers

Comment: Hi again - Do you know the exact meaning of localhost?? Because most of the time even `http://localhost:8080` will not work when `http://127.0.0.1:8080` does. Yet in another usecase I have [elm-reactor](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-reactor) listening (locally) on port 8000 and `127.0.0.1:8000` doesn't work while `localhost:8000` does... I'm quite confused I would have thought that `localhost` is just an alias for the loopback interface address returned by `ip addr`...

Comment: Well, in my experience it is supposed to be an alias for the loopback address as you say. But I also think it is possible to reconfigure that hostname to map to any IP address (in theory). What do you get when you do a `host localhost` or `nslookup localhost`?

Port binding is done on an IP-level, so hostname should be irrelevant. Also note that any 127.x.x.x address actually maps to the loopback interface, meaning you can bind services to 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3 etc. exclusively. However, on Mac you need to explicitly enable every address.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ip routing but I guess `127.x.x.x` is what actually means `127.0.0.1/8`? I'm under arch and don't have these commands I think they were replaced by `drill` in ldns but this just gives me my network ip...  Well anyway I added `127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain` in `/etc/hosts` and now I can find both local servers as expected! Cheers